# Trying to Create Python Package for Internal Use

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to create a package of my simple python program, so that i could distribute it to other developers internally. I am able to import the package in my virtual environment but when I try to install it through pip outside of that virtual environment, I get following error:

```
C:\mypackages\cmk>python -m pip install cmk
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cmk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cmk
```

Following is my directory structure:

```
C:\mypackages\cmk>dir

29/07/2021  09:05 PM    <DIR>          .
29/07/2021  09:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
29/07/2021  08:55 PM    <DIR>          .venv
29/07/2021  09:00 PM    <DIR>          cmk
29/07/2021  05:53 PM             1,312 config.yml
29/07/2021  08:57 PM               201 requirements.txt
29/07/2021  08:34 PM               290 setup.py
29/07/2021  09:04 PM                98 test.py
```

In above directory structure, the cmk contains my actual program and my setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='cmk',
      version='0.1',
      packages=['cmk'],
)
```

I have checked and all the dependencies in requirements.txt are installed already.

```
C:\mypackages\cmk>pip freeze
awscli==1.19.98
boto3==1.16.53
botocore==1.20.98
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
docutils==0.15.2
jmespath==0.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
retrying==1.3.3
rsa==4.5
s3transfer==0.4.2
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.26.2
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy to [pypi](https://pypi.org/) or to [local](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/) repository.